# How to try run django server

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write test that will test if django app is runnable. I just want to try run django server and if everything is ok return code 0 otherwise another code.

```
python manage.py runserver
```

This command run infinite loop and I need to stop it by *CTRL + C*. And that is the problem. I would like to run it just for few second.

Note:
I am runnig django on linux.

Comment: On Linux you can use the `timeout` function for that.

Comment: Seems like you're testing the wrong thing.

Comment: @erip I know it is not good idea to test this way but I want it as simply as possible.

Comment: What kind of things do you expect to fail? Keeping things simple doesn't mean testing the wrong thing. If you expect config to fail, test configs. If you expect types to cause errors, run a linter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the case to check within a test you can also use
[`django.test.testcases.LiveServerTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase). This class will start you application in the background.

This is more stable than just to run Django for 5 seconds as perhaps it will take more than 5 seconds to start your application for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

On a Linux system, you can use [**`timeout`**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) for that. For example:

```
$ timeout 5 python manage.py runserver
```

It will run the command for 5 seconds, and then terminate the program. In case the command times out - something we want here - the exit code is 124. In case the command times out (this is usually because an error occurs) - the exit code is the exit code of the inner command (so `python manage.py runserver`).

So we could make it work like:

```
#!/bin/bash

timeout 5 python manage.py runserver

# return non-zero exit code in case exit code of timeout is not 124
test "$?" -eq "124"
```

Note that there are better ways to test an application, and testing an application by simply checking if the server runs, is not exhaustive at all: from the moment a user fetches a page, a lot of things can go wrong.